# Best Practices for implementing a modal Alert View using Cocoa Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Does anyone have any best practices, tips & tricks, or recommendations for how to create modal Alert Views with Cocoa Touch?

I like to think there is a way to make this difficult task trivial or at least easier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
void AlertWithMessage(NSString *message)
{
/* open an alert with an OK button */
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Name of the Application" 
                                message:message
                                delegate:nil 
                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Comment: As you'll have figured out with arc, the [alert release] has to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I just use UIAlertView to display modal alerts. What additional functionality are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the UICatalog sample code from Apple. It shows the usage of both Alerts and Sheets on the phone.